# App crashes when adding Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

My app was working fine until I added Facebook login. I did everything the same as I did on my other application but still getting error. I added facebook sdk and also initialized it. I registered my app in facebook website. Still don't understand the problem.

```js
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078): Process: com.sam.sports, PID: 30078
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.FacebookActivity
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at com.facebook.internal.Validate.hasFacebookActivity(Validate.java:176)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:198)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:174)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at com.sam.sports.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:59)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5280)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
01-02 23:05:02.192: E/AndroidRuntime(30078):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sam.sports"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.sam.sports.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
         <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider975617842510005"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
         <activity
            android:name=".CreateLog"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```html
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";
    
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton login;
    String name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_login);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_login);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        
///////////////////////////////////////////////// Facebook Login Starts ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");



        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
         RequestData();
        } 
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
          if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
          }
         }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

          if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){

           RequestData();

          } 

         }

         @Override
         public void onCancel() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
         }
        });

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Facebook Login Ends/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);
                        
                        //add "option" to SharedPreference
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                  Editor editor = settings.edit();
                  editor.putString("option", "0");
                     editor.commit();

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Facebook Login Starts///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    public void RequestData(){
     GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

      @Override
      public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
       try {
        if(json != null){
         //String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");

         name = json.getString("name");
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
      Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("option", "1");
      editor.putString("name", name);
      editor.commit();
      Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      
      startActivity(main);
      finish();

        }

       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
    } 


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Facebook Login Ends///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

}
```

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: No eclipse. @CreativeAndroid

Comment: Everything  seems  good.  Try to clean and build project again

Answer (score 1):

Facebook permissions should be seperated:

```
login.setReadPermissions("public_profile","email");
```

and
there is no need of:
 `login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`
 because while clicking `login` button it will call :
`login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()` method to invoke `com.facebook.FacebookActivity`

Comment: have u added facebook sdk to library?

Comment: I think there is some confusion in validating your package name: check package name you have registered is this `com.sam.sports` and the launcher activity is also

Comment: Yes they are both same.

Comment: unable to find the error, if it's showing internal validate error means then the information what you have given to facebook app registration and what you are using is mismatching.The package name what you have given here`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sam.sports" ` and the first activity name `android:name=".LoginActivity"` here check whether package is : `com.sam.sports.LoginActivity` or `com.sam.sports.app.LoginActivity` for first activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99546/discussion-between-giridharan-a-r-and-somnath-pal).